# The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http' for Linkedin

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the connections API from Linkedin. When I use the make the call it returns an error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.*example*.com/ from frame with URL https://api.linkedin.com/uas/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC1.26335-1404#www.*example*.com&xdm_c=default4901&xdm_p=1&mode=cors. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.
```

Anyone know why this error occurs?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I think it says that the page with JavaScript calling LinkedIn api has an http:// URL, but it should be https://, no?

Comment: The error is saying "The parent page and the iframe both need to be in the same protocol." Means they both have to be http or https. You can not mix them.

Comment: Are you using Ajax calls, or are you embedding an Iframe?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the http / https bit.

Add "&callback=?" to the URL you are calling, and it will do some magic!

Like this!

```
var url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + id + "?access_token=" + instagramtoken +  + "&callback=?"
```

Saw this solution somewhere on stackoverlfow but cannor remeber where. It solved my problem!

hth